# How to modify this jQuery code that centers a div so that it centers it even if the browser's windows is being resized?

Tags: jquery

I found this code at StackOverflow:

```
/* Center Dish Popup */
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}

$('#dish-popup').center();
```

It centers the div. But the div remains in the same place if you resize the browser's window. I would like to know how to change the code so that the div re-centers itself while the browser's window is being re-sized.

Comment: For your reference: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#dish-popup').center();
});
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Call the code from the [resize event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#dish-popup').center();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always wrap it in a `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#dish-popup').center();
}
```